# Why does the node window close when I try to open a video or a html file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http, video

Whenever I open: "localhost:8080/", or "localhost:8080/video.mp4" in my browser, Node.js stops running. When localhost:8080/ is loaded the page does display, but the script is shutdown. Also, the video doesn't work at all.

This is my code:

```
var url = require('url');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var util = require('util');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
  var q = url.parse(req.url, true);

  switch(true) {


  case q.pathname==='/':
    fs.readFile('./Crazy_Network.html',function(err, html){ 
        res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        res.write(html);
        res.end();
}); 

        break;

 case endsWith('.mp4'):
    let fileInfo = util.promisify(fs.stat);
    let filename = '.'+q.pathname;

    let { size } = await fileInfo(filename);
    let fileExtension = path.extname(filename).replace('.', '');
    let { range } = req.headers;

    if (range) {
        let [start, end] = range.replace(/bytes=/, '').split('-')
        start = parseInt(start, 10); // starting bytes
        // end = end ? parseInt(end, 10) : size - 1 // end of file unless specified
        end = Math.min(start + 5000, size - 1); // 5000 bytes starting from start byte or end of file, whichever is smaller
        res.writeHead(206, { // HTTP 206 - Because it is Partial Content
            'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${size}`,
            'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
            'Content-Length': (end - start) + 1,// denotes the number of bytes requested and not the entire file size
            'Content-Type': `video/${fileExtension}`,
        });
        fs.createReadStream(filename, { start, end }).pipe(res);
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': `video/${fileExtension}`,
            'Content-Length': size,
        });
        fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(res);
    }
    res.end();
    break;

  default:
    res.end('Pathname used doesn\'t do anything except this.')
    break;
} 

}).listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on port 8080');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**path.parse(url).pathname**

[Node documentation for `path.parse`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#pathparsepath) doesn't list a `pathname` property for objects returned by the method (so looking one up will evaluate to `undefined`).  Replacing

```
case q.pathname==='/':
```

with

```
case q.base==="":
```

may provide a temporary solution but doesn't check if the request is for the root directory. I suggest console logging `q` and then experimenting some to determine what to use based on your particular requirements.

**Syntax Error**

```
case endsWith(".mp4"):
```

is almost certainly a syntax error given `endsWith` is a String method. I would expect it to generate a run time error when (and if) the value expression is evaluated, crashing node in the process.

Replacing it with

```
case q.ext.toLowerCase() === ".mp4":
```

hopefully resolve the issue description provided in the post. Don't forget that filenames are *case sensisitive* on linux systems.

---

If you are not already aware of it I highly recommend [Express](https://expressjs.com/) - a framework for writing nodejs servers.